# How to correctly call jQuery function that uses HTML elements?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm new to the use of jQuery so the problem I'm facing should be fairly straight forward. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is load a variety of simple text-only pages within DIV elements of my site, and with a navigation bar hide/unhide these individual DIVs.

DIVs are correctly loaded the requested pages using an script block. However, what is not working correctly is toggling the visibility of these DIV blocks. I've narrowed it down to a jQuery function I've created which blocks the entire script call whenever I refer to any of the DIV blocks. Let me explain better with a code snippet.

This is is some very simple code that, on the click of a menu link, runs a hide function then shows the corresponding DIV element.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {           
        console.log("document ready."); <-- does NOT get called with hideDivs()

        $('#button1').click(function(){
            hideDivs();
            $("#page1").show();
        }); 

        $('#button2').click(function(){
            hideDivs();
            $("#page2").show();
        });
    });
```

This is the hideDivs() function, JUST above the ready function:

```
    function hideDivs() 
    {
        $("#page1").hide(); <-- These lines cause the entire
        $("#page2").hide(); <-- <script> block to note get called.
    }
```

Finally, *page1* and *page2* are created with a script block halfway inside the page:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>

<script>
    $("#page1").html('<object style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%; height: 500px;" data="page1.php">').show();
    $("#page2").html('<object style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%; height: 500px;" data="page2.php">').hide();
</script>
```

Why then is it that the top SCRIPT block fails with the hideDivs() function? I've tried placing it inside the $( document ).ready function with no change. Again, if the function is blank, or contains something simple like 'console.log' it works, but when referring to DIV tags it breaks.

Even stranger, the code that makes the function FAIL, WORKS if I simply rewrite the code as such:

```
        $('#button1').click(function(){
            $("#page1").hide(); <-- This works fine
            $("#page2").hide(); <-- (page1 repeated to match function code)
            $("#page1").show();
        });
```

I have quite a few pages so I would much rather be able to use a function as not to have lots of repetitive code.

I have no errors displayed in my javascript console. I've looked closely at functions calls with StackOverflow and Google searches but couldn't spot a solution. I'm sure I've made a really silly mistake I'm overlooking, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What errors are being thrown by the browser when loading your page and/or executing that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of the whole function to hide your divs, you can simply put a class on each one and hide them by selecting that class. For example, each page Div give a class="clickablePages", and then do:

```
$(".clickablePages").hide();
```

that will simply hide all the divs that you have added the class to.

As for repeating all the button clicks for each button, you can simply do it in one function based on the id of the button. You can again put a class on all of the buttons as well, trigger the function by selecting the class and then grab the id you need within that function. something like this:

```
$('.buttonclick').click(function(){
        var pageID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#page" + pageID).show();
    });
```

In this case, if your buttons just had an id of '1' or '2' that matched the page number, it would only show the div for that page number. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Quinny, adding a class solved it for me, removing the need for a separate function. The second bit is appreciated too, the cleaner the code the better :).

Comment: No problem,
yes the theory of that is right, but $(this).attr('id') will return the id of the button you have clicked. So if your button has an id of 1, then  "#page" + pageID = "#page1".
Although you can play around with the naming of IDs as its best not to just have an ID of only a number.